# Send message to jms queue throws AMQ119031: Unable to validate user exception

Tags: jms, wildfly-11

Code to send message to JMS queue in Wildfly 11.0.0-Final is throwing ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ119031: Unable to validate user] exception if I provide credentials to createConnection() method.

Followed steps mentioned in below quickstart guide to add user, create queue
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-jms

It works fine if I disable security in standalone-full.xml

Below given are details about the exceptions and the code to send a message to queue

**Exception:**

```
2018-01-08 18:20:44,641 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (default I/O-10) AMQ224018: Failed to create session: ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ119031: Unable to validate user]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:144)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createSession(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1283)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handleCreateSession(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:158)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handlePacket(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:81)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:633)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:379)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:362)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:621)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:69)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:443)
at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:379)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

**Code**

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, Constants.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, Constants.PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, Constants.USERNAME);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Constants.PASSWORD);
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(Constants.JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY);

            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(Constants.JMS_DESTINATION);

            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(Constants.USERNAME,Constants.PASSWORD);
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

            Message msg = session.createTextMessage(Constants.DEFAULT_MESSAGE+"1");
            producer.send(msg);
```

Any help on this appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't add any application user for the queue.
You have to add an application user with username and password that must match the values you are passing for the Constants.USERNAME and Constants.PASSWORD.
For adding an application user you have to start wildfy and run the "add-user" script you can find it within the bin directory of your wildfly installation and following the instruction.